# Trying to add two tags to a question. One of them was a synonym to the other, but did not reveal this, and showed its original description

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonym-process

I've just posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74042733/invoking-awk-in-a-makefile-recipe), which as you can see has the `awk` tag applied.

I then tried to add the `gawk` tag. I wasn't aware that it had become a synonym for `awk`, and the version of `awk` I was using was indeed GNU. As you can see, the tag's original description was shown, with no indication that it was a synonym:

[image]

When the question was posted, the tag was silently deleted, without the user (me) being notified of this, or given the reason.

I think there may be one or more bugs here:

1. The tag being given as an option at all.
2. The description failing to mention that it was a synonym of a tag I'd already added.
3. The failure to notify when the tag was deleted.
4. The failure to give a reason - I even attempted a tag edit just to restore the `gawk` tag, and had to do some detective work to find out what was going on.

(Though I don't know if these actually are bugs, or if this is *not-a-bug-its-a-feature* behaviour.)

Comment: The [Gawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations) tag [is a synonym of the AWK tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/synonyms). (There is also [a list of *all* tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)! With a search facility.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I know it is. Or at least, I know that now. I'm pointing out that this wasn't made clear when I tried to add both tags to the question, and that the silent deletion of the gawk tag without notification doesn't seem like correct behaviour to me. It certainly caused confusion. And since the original description was shown for the gawk tag, this made it look like it wasn't a synonym.

Comment: Agreed. The silent substitution doesn't follow the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) (POLA). Users have to already know about tag synonyms to know why it happens (probably very few do).

Comment: It's because the tag is a synonym but not merged, thus the [gawk] tag itself actually still exists and there are 984 existing questions still tagged with [gawk] (that I can't find a way to search them without being redirected to [awk]).

Comment: Browsing [the oldest questions of `[awk] is:q gawk`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=30&tab=Newest&q=%5bawk%5d%20is%3aq%20gawk&searchOn=3) shows that [gawk] is still there (and it's by design as per [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/241919): "*However, existing questions tagged with the synonym tag that were using it before the synonym was created and were not edited later will continue to use the synonym tag.*")

Comment: I agree that the current behavior in this situation is not ideal. It seems like there are a few different ways this could be fixed... Should we prevent the edit from being saved, and show some kind of error message when trying add the new tag (and if so, what message)? Should we just replace the original tag with the tag it's been made a synonym of (and if so, how should we communicate what's happening and why it's happening)?

Comment: @V2Blast maybe adding "synonymized to: [master-tag]" on the popup might help, similar to 'also: [synonymized-tag], [synonymized-tag2]" on [the master tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2uGB.png).